# How to select an item that is in a drop down menu coded in CSS for Selenium IDE?

Tags: javascript, css, selenium, drop-down-menu

Thanks so much for reading my question. I am inquiring about selecting an item that exists in a drop down menu. The drop down menu is coded in CSS.

The change in the Javascript is from

**a class="chzn-single"**

to selecting the item

**a class="chzn-single-with-drop"**

back to

**a class="chzn-single"**

I look forward to any and all help. If there's any questions, please don't hesitate to reach out and thanks again for looking at my question.

Comment: Whatdo you mean by *"drop down menu **coded** in CSS"*? You want to change the current selected `<option>` in a  `<select>` based on the  `<option>`'s classes? Is this it?

Comment: Can u show us your code? It's hard to think a solution just from class name

Comment: <div id="id_patient_chzn">, <a class="chzn=single">, <div class="chzn-drop", <div class="chzn-search", "ul class="chzn-results", <li id="id_patient_chzn_o_0"

Answer (score 0):

If using Jquery to select an element by class name

```
$(".chzn-single")
```

if you dont have jquery included you can do this by vanilla Js by Declaring a function

```
function getElementByClass (className, parent) {
  parent || (parent = document);
  var descendants= parent.getElementsByTagName('*'), i=-1, e, result=[];
  while (e=descendants[++i]) {
    ((' '+(e['class']||e.className)+' ').indexOf(' '+className+' ') > -1) && result.push(e);
  }
  return result;
}
```

and calling the declared function

```
var element1 = getElementByClass("a", "chzn-single");
```

Comment: We are still looking for some kind of solution, as we have already declared an element...

Comment: So what I currently have is click css=a.chzn-single>span, click css=div.chzn-search>input, type css=div.chzn-search>input ${cl_sur},$(cl_boy}, clickAt css=div.chzn-drop id=id_patient_chzn_o_0.active-result.result-selected, breaks after this.